# How to build a jquery selector that stops traversing deeper on match?

Tags: jquery

How can I build a jquery selector, that does not traverse deeper on match? It should not select any children with the same selector.

```
$(".foo").each(function(){}); //how to modify '.foo'?


<div>
  <div class="foo">
    <!--select this-->
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    <!--select this-->
    <div class="foo">
      <!--do not select-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.foo:first')`?

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty method:

```
$('.foo').not('.foo .foo')
```

This will not select 'foo' children of 'foo'.

Edit:

if you give your outer div an id, then you can do:

```
$("#outer>.foo").each(function(){});
```

That will select '.foo' elements that are direct children of '#outer'.

This is faster then the first method!

Comment: Nice idea! As long I do not find any cleaner solution this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Child Selector (“parent > child”) is best practice to do this kind of work.

The child combinator (A > B) can be thought of as a more specific form of the descendant combinator (A B) in that it selects only first-level descendants.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btSelect').click(function () {
                $("#panel1 > .foo").css("border", "3px double red");
            });
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="btSelect" class="btn btn-success">Get First Level</button>
<br><br>
    <div id="panel1">
        <div class="foo">Menu 1</div>
        <div class="foo">Menu 2
            <div class="foo">Menu 2.1</div>
            <div class="foo">Menu 2.2
                <div class="foo">Menu 2.2.1</div>
                <div class="foo">Menu 2.2.2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="foo">Menu 2.3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="foo">Menu 3
            <div class="foo">Menu 3.1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="foo">Menu 4</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also thought about that, does not work because the .foo class is not necessarily a direct sibling, and it should work with "grandchildren" too. Poul Bak's solution works like that.